# Apply textcolor to button in code - android

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to change a textcolor on a button.

My selector looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
```

If I set android:textColor="@drawable/buttontext" in my activity xml it works perfectly. But if I in my code do something like this button.setTextColor(R.drawable.buttontext) it doesn't work. It is not because the buttons isn't initialized, because I have set its onClickListener which works perfectly. And when a do button.setTextColor(Color.white), it also works.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I figured out how to do it, and the keyword was ColorstateList.
In the code I did this instead:

```
            XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.drawable.buttontext);
            ColorStateList colors;
            try {
                colors = ColorStateList.createFromXml(getResources(), parser);
                buttonList.setTextColor(colors);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTextColor` takes an ARGB int value, not a resource id.

Try `setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.yourResource))`

Comment: That doesn't work. What I want to do, is make the textcolor change when the button is pressed.

Comment: Then pull those colors out into their own resources, resources.getColor() expects a color resource, not a selector.  You can reference the new color resources in your selector to avoid duplication.